# What is the best practice to delete all relationships in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I need to delete all relationships of product. I got error when I trying to delete item with relationships. Here is my code:

```
public function getDelete(Product $product)
{
    $name = $product->name;

    $product->Field()->Data()->delete();
    $product->Field()->delete();
    $product->delete();

    return redirect('products')->with('success', 'Product <b>'.$name.'</b> successfully deleted.');
}
```

Here is models:

```
public function Field()
{
    return $this->hasMany("\App\ProductField", 'product_id','id');
}

public function Data()
{
    return $this->hasMany("\App\ProductFieldData", 'product_field_id','id');
}
```

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2101: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::Data()

This error I got If product don't have a ProductFieldData. But I think its must be skipped if don't have relationships data?

How to delete product all relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach ($product->Field()->Data as $data) {
    $data->delete();
}
```

You're dealing with a collection and you can't perform the delete function on a collection of items, so you have to iterate over it.

By the way, shouldnt you do this by using `ON DELETE CASCADE`? You should do some reseach on that, it'll save you a lot of time!

Comment: same error ;) I added foreign key and setting on delete cascade, but I need firstly delete by the Laravel

Comment: @Haroldas did it work? Would be glad if you accept this as answer if it did :)